# Robots.txt file not crawled by Google

Tags: force.com-sites, google

We use a force site, with a second level domain like http://mycompany.force.com/site1

The salesforce configuration allows a robots.txt file at this address

http://mycompany.force.com/site1/robots.txt

But in the [Google robots.txt specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) the robots.txt file in the location  is not allowed and Google will not crawl it.

As Google said "The robots.txt file must be in the top-level directory of the host, accessible though the appropriate protocol and port number".

How can we resolve this problem?

Is possible to configure a robots.txt file on the root address http://mycompany.force.com ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After some googling I found the solution.

You need to create a new Site and leave empty the web site suffix.
With this solution you can also configure the favicon for your website.

[image: Root web site configuration for robots.txt]